# Difference between web.config and machine.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis

What is the difference between `web.config` and `machine.config`?

I have read that:-

> The web.config files specify configuration settings for a particular
>   web application, and are located in the application's root directory;
>   the machine.config file specifies configuration settings for all of
>   the websites on the web server, and is located in
>   $WINDOWSDIR$\Microsoft.Net\Framework\Version\Config.

Is there anything which I am missing or any other technical aspect? I want to know more about both the files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each CLR version has a `machine.config` file, along with an additional `web.config` file, which I refer to as the "machine level web.config file".

Additionally, as you note, each web application also has a `web.config` file. Directories inside a web application can also have `web.config` files too.

Now, the key point is that config files inherit from each other. That means, a web application will read settings defined in the `machine.config` file and the machine level `web.config` file (for its given framework version), and its own `web.config` file.

A common use case for defining things in the `machine.config` would be to share values between many applications on the server, like a connection string perhaps, or SMTP server settings, things like that.

Comment: Great answer but I have a little fix: It's not "Each .NET Framework" but each CLR version. (e.x. .net fx 3.0 comes without its own CLR hence, no new machine.config for that .net fw)

Comment: ...except that since .NET Core 1.0 (and .NET 5 and later), there is no-longer any `machine.config` file, instead the alternative is `runtimeconfig.json` (sometimes erroneously called `runtime.config` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/ )

Answer (score 4):

Those are some of the most important details; although actually, `machine.config` goes beyond simply configuration for ASP.NET itself. There is another file you should look into, which (I think) is in the same location as `machine.config`; that is the 'root' `web.config`, which goes between `machine.config` and the site-specific `web.config` files, and is, of course, ASP.NET specific.

Some of the settings you change at the server level in the IIS management console are performed in the root `web.config`.

Note that this hierarchy is per-.NET version; (2.0 has one; 4.0 has its own)

Another note: You can have sub `web.config` files in directories and/or sub-applications off a site's root which further modify the 'base'.

Finally, one caveat: Not all settings can be overridden in sub-level web.config files. It is possible (and some are, by default) to lock down certain settings at any level of the hierarchy described here.

Answer (score 4):

Let me clear it out:-
 in ASP.NET, there is a configuration files hierarchy and machine.config file lies at the root
meaning machine.config file contain configuration settings that are applied on each web application, you created. It exists in Windows/Microsoft .NET/Framework/[version]/config
You will find a web.config file in the same physical path(I give it name A).This web.config file inherits configuration settings from machine.config.now you have your application folder in which you have web.config(at root level). This web.config( I name it B) inherits configuration settings from A. If you have web.config in application folder's sub-directories than sub-directory web.config inherits configuration settings from B and that is how the ladder goes down

Answer (score 2):

The `machine.config` is the ultimate master config file on your system with a lot of default settings. When you use web.config files, which is done in a cascading order, you're actually overwriting these settings with new ones.

Answer (score 1):

**Machine.Config**

- This is automatically installed when you install Visual Studio. Net.
- This is also called machine level configuration file.
- Only one machine.config file exists on a server.
- This file is at the highest level in the configuration hierarchy.

**Web.Config**

- This is automatically created when you create an ASP.Net web application project.
- This is also called application level configuration file.
- This file inherits setting from the machine.config